# Will running several thematic blogs help speed up indexing of my site by Google?

Tags: seo, google, blog

I've recently started a standalone site that contains multiple tests and quizes on a specific subject. My main concern is that it's being indexed by Google/Bing very slowly.

My intent is:

1. Take some new tests that did not make it to the site yet.
2. Create several free blogs on Blogger and WordPress.
3. Distribute all the unused tests between the blogs.
4. Have every page of every blog end with "If you want more of these, go here" and a link to a relevant page on the main site.
5. Regularly add more pages to the blogs.

Advantages:

- this strategy is easy to accomplish for me. It's most important because I don't have resources for paid promotion and do not have any knowledge of social networks.

Disadvantages:

- my site provides better user experience for solving tests than any free blog does
- Google would probably find out that the site and the blogs are owned by the same person and disregard the links
- it will take much time moving all the tests from the blogs back to the main site once it gains some reputation.

Should I follow this strategy to promote the site? Or should I do something else (or just wait patiently until Google does the indexing stuff)?

Comment: It sounds like your marketing plan is to distribute your content over several or many places. This is not a good idea. Create your site with your content. You can provide unique, interesting, and complimentary content elsewhere, just do not take what should be on your site and put it all over the place. Cheers!!